# Hummer H3 - no crank, no start

Tags: hummer, h3, keyless-ignition

I have a Hummer H3. I tried replacing the key start with keyless ignition. Unfortunately, it didn't work, so I tried to put everything back the way it was. Now, there is a problem. They key will go to the on position and turn on the accessories, but the car won't crank or start. The display panel reads a lot of errors that are not accurate. For example, "no fuel" (The car does have fuel), or "breaking error" (the break lights work, the emergency break can be pressed down and released). The steering wheel is locked and I cannot switch from parking either. The constant ignition wire reads 5.1 volts (It's supposed to read 12), and I believe this is the reason it won't start.

WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR

I have determined that the ignition wire goes all the way back to one of the harnesses that go into the BCM. The BCM has two harnesses plugged in. One of them was reading 12 volts, the other one, where the ignition wire originates from, reads 5.1. I thought that disconnecting the battery, unplugging the two plugs, and then reconnecting the battery, would reset the module and fix the problem. However, now, while the other harness still reads 12 volts, the  one I'm concerned with reads 0.

I have opened up the module to make sure that nothing is burned or browned inside. I am currently thinking it requires reprogramming.

Can someone offer any help to make the car run again?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, it's a Hummer H3 2007.

Comment: Presumably you're using an aftermarket product (gizmo) for keyless. If the instructions call for the gizmo to be mounted to a grounded metal body part, you must mount it or it won't work. If the gizmo has a wire with a ring connector that must be grounded to the body, make sure whatever it's grounded to is actually a good ground.